# Rational homotopy type of Hilbert scheme components

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, rt.representation-theory, rational-homotopy-theory

What is known about rational homotopy type of irreducible component of $Hilb^n(\mathbb C^k)$ containing configuration space? I've searched arXiv for a while and found nothing but surmise that Betti numbers are still not computed even for $k=3$ case.

Comment: You might know this already but for the case of $k=2$ or surfaces in general the cohomology is intricately related to Vertex algebras https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0009132.pdf

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know anything about Hilbert schemes, but if this irreducible component is homotopy equivalent to a configuration space of $\mathbb{C}^k$ then the answer is "a lot" and I can give references.

Comment: Inclusion of configuration space is (un)fortunately nullhomotopic; the question is about the fiber over $n$-tuple point. It's possible that they are related nonetheless, because Fulton compactification (which is an easy-going analogue of Hilb) can be used in computation of Conf dga model.